# Convert specific sheet with unoconv

Tags: csv, converters, xlsx, unoconv

I have xlsx file with multiple sheets and i need to convert it to csv file. I need convert only one specific sheet, i'm using unoconv but unoconv convert only first sheet from file and finish.

I try to find some flag from unoconv documentation for choosing specific sheet, but failed.

Comment: https://github.com/unoconv/unoconv/issues/198